# なかったこと in なかったことにできますよ

Tags: translation

> それが私にとっての「写真を撮る」という行為の大前提だったし、いまでもそうだ。
>   撮れた写真の背後には、膨大な量の、思うように撮れなかった写真や、シャッターを切る勇気がなく、存在すらできなかった写真がある。写真は偶然に撮れるが、撮れなかった写真に偶然はない。逆に、撮れなかった写真にこそ、撮る人間の本質が隠されている。
>   デジタルの世界は私たちの目の前に、「**消しますか？ あなたが望むなら、なかったことにできますよ**」という禁断の選択を提示する。

May I know what  bolded sentence actually means?

> My attempted translation: Do you want to erase it? If you wish to, you
>   can do something that you have not done.

But this sounds a little bit illogical, how can one do something that he/she has not done? Did I misunderstand the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

今までなかったこと is something that hasn't existed or happened before.

Essentially, なかったこと would be something that didn't exist. So, なかったことにする would mean 'to make it so that it didn't exist.'

> 「消しますか？ あなたが望むなら、なかったことにできますよ」

Shall we erase it? If you want, we can make it so that (it is like) it was never there.

A couple examples can be found [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%84%A1%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B).

Answer (score 9):

～～ことにする is a phrase that means "to regard it as~~" "to pretend that~~".
cf: See 「～～ということにできる」 in [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53808/9831). Also 「～～ことになる」 explained in [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17963/9831) might be loosely related.
<sub>(As you may know, ～～ことにする can also mean "decide to do~~".)</sub>

> こと
>   ❽㋑活用語を名詞化する。...
>   （語法）(1)「こと」は文法的に働くだけで、何らかの意味を追加するわけではない。(2) この応用として、次のような助動詞相当に働く連語がある。⇒ ... **・・・ことにする**（意思に基づく決定。また、**みなし行為**。）・・・ことになる（事態の成立・口裏合わせ・必然的結論など）
>   (明鏡国語辞典)

So in your example:

> なかったことにできますよ。
>   "We can pretend that it never happened/existed." → "We can undo it."

Examples:

> - 「今のは聞かなかった**ことにして**。」
>     "Please pretend you didn't hear that." → "Forget what I just said." "I'll take back my word."
> - 「今回の契約はなかった**ことにしてください**。」
>     "Please pretend the contract never existed." → "I want to annul/cancel the contract." "Please forget the contract."
> - 「見なかった**ことにしよう**・・・。」
>     "I'll pretend I didn't see this..." (≂ "I'll just forget/ignore this...")