# Help a translating this phrase

Tags: grammar, conjugations, phrases, conditionals

I was reading a manga and the grammar of this phrase kinda confused me:

> 今日三条くんの会社からなかったことにしてくれって連絡あったらしくて。

For context, the character is saying this to a second character about a third character's company, but the sense of the phrase just isn't clear to me. Can someone help me break it down to understand it better?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56600/5010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 今日/三条くん/の/会社/から/なかった/こと/に/してくれ/って/連絡/あった/らしくて。
>
> Apparently, we have been contacted today by Sanjo's company, and they told us to act as if it didn't happen